# Error 324 Empty_response only on free webhost with fpassthru, readfile, file_get_contents

Tags: php, readfile

i'm a little confused.

```
$l = $_REQUEST['l'];

$arr = get_headers($l);
foreach($arr as $a => $b){
    if($a == "6"){
        $r = str_replace('Location: ', '', $b);
    }
}
readfile($r);
```

this code works fine on my local apche server but when i try it on a free web host (000webhost) i get an empty response. even when i echo a random string it doesn't give a response until i remove the readfile. i have also tried replacing the readfile with file get contents as well as the combination of fopen and fpassthru. ideas?

Comment: turn or `error_reporting` and watch for errors

Comment: Most likely your webhost does not allow you to access `http://` addresses. Enable `error_reporting` to gain more information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the readfile() functionality is currently disabled on the web host you're using, 
try using another host which support this functionality or you better ask the free host support team to activate this functionality.

Comment: The functionality could be better worded as enabling [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/allow_url_fopen).

Comment: but they do allow all of these functions i've tested them before and they have advertised that they support these functions.